# What is the etymology of "replenish"?

Tags: etymology

Where does the word "replenish" come from, and what does it mean? I know it is used as a form of "refill", but is that how it was originally?

Comment: Did you have a question about 'plenum'? It's in the title, but not the question body.

Comment: Not here, maybe in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Webster's 1828 dictionary gives this definition:**

In the transitive form:

> REPLEN'ISH, verb transitive [L. re and plenus, full.] :
>
> 1. To fill; to stock with numbers or abundance.
>    The magazines are **replenished** with corn.
>    The springs are **replenished** with water.
>    Multiply and **replenish** the earth. Gen 1.

In the intransitive form:

> REPLEN'ISH, verb intransitive: To recover former fullness.

**Another answer gives this:**

> ... "replenish" is of French/Latin origin and "fill" is of Anglo-Saxon/Germanic origin. Interestingly, roll the clock back a couple thousand years and they should be the same word. Germanic languages tended to turn P into F, so the ancestor of both words was probably "pell" or "pill".

**In short:**

If it is a transitive verb ("Replenish the bin.") it means **fill**, if intransitive ("It will replenish", it means **refill**.

Answer (score 4):

It means (according to my trusty New Webster's Encyclopedic Dictionary):

> 1. to make full or complete again
> 2. to supply with fresh fuel
> 3. to fill again or anew
> 4. (intransitively) to become full or complete again

According to another dictionary (the one built-in in Mac OS X), the origin of the word can be traced to Old French (and further to Latin, of course), as follows:

> ORIGIN late Middle English (in the
>   sense [supply abundantly] ): from Old
>   French repleniss-, lengthened stem of
>   replenir, from re- ‘again’ (also
>   expressing intensive force) + plenir
>   ‘fill’ (from Latin plenus ‘full’ ).

Based on that, I don't think it has had other meanings in English earlier. As to why should one use this word instead of the less fancy **refill** – I have no idea, except perhaps to show off & try to sound educated.

Answer (score 1):

As reported from the NOAD:

> ORIGIN late Middle English (in the sense [supply abundantly]): from Old French *repleniss-*, lengthened stem of *replenir*, from *re-* 'again' (also expressing intensive force) + *plenir* 'fill' (from Latin *plenus* 'full').

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster's 11th Collegiate Dictionary

> transitive verb
>
> 1. a : to fill with persons or animals : *STOCK* b archaic : to
>      supply fully : *PERFECT* c : to fill
>      with inspiration or power : *NOURISH*
> 2. a : to fill or build up again  b : to make
>      good : *REPLACE*  intransitive verb :
>      to become full : fill up again

Answer (score 0):

Jonik is right, "replenish" is of French/Latin origin and "fill" is of Anglo-Saxon/Germanic origin. Interestingly, roll the clock back a couple thousand years and they should be the same word. Germanic languages tended to turn P into F, so the ancestor of both words was probably "pell" or "pill".

Comment: Anyone know latin? Is the word in there?

Comment: I once thought that plenish was a word and that re-plenish meant refill, and that **plen** meant full.

Comment: In French after you *replenir* something it's *plein*

Comment: Ah, so I was right! Just hasn't gotten to English yet. `;)`